# Mass Effect 3 will be on Origin, how will this affect me with my two other Mass Effect games being on Steam?

Tags: steam, origin, mass-effect-series

As you know EA had a fall out with Steam earlier this year (2011). This meant that any newly released games by EA would only be available through Origin and not any other source.

This is troubling for me as I do not know how it will affect me in keeping my character consistency throughout all the games (as you maintain your character stats, features) all through the Mass Effect series.

Do you think Mass Effect 3 will be able to detect my previous games even though they are located in the Steam folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Mass Effect and Mass Effect 2 saves your games in a non-Steam-specific location (`[My Documents]/Bioware/Mass Effect` and `[My Documents]/Bioware/Mass Effect 2`) Mass Effect 3 should not have any problem finding your previous save games.

Comment: Thanks for the swift and concise response! Have A Happy New Year

Comment: @rayman24 You might want to accept the answer, indicating the problem has been solved and [upvote it when you can do so](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up).